# A map-like container

Tags: c++, data-structures

I need a special container which is like a multimap of two types: `T1` and `T2`: each "row" in the container contains a `T1` and `T2`. The requirements I need from it are:

1. Fast insertion of a row(`T1` and `T2`), O(log n) in multimap which is ok.
2. Fast query of all rows which contain `T1`, O(log n) in multimap which is ok.
3. Fast removal of a row based on `T1` and `T2`, O(k * log n) in multimap which is bad.

Is there a better container for these requirements in Boost or SGI STL libraries?
Edit:
If it helps anybody, `T1` is an `enum` and `T2` is a pair of two `int`s.

Comment: If you can add any insight as to the properties of T1 and T2, that would be useful.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: added in edit.

Comment: Depending on the types `T1` and `T2`, perhaps `boost::unordered_multimap`?

Comment: @Chad: it still has poor performance on 3.

Comment: Are `T1` and ` T2` together a composite key?  Erasing from an unordered map by key value (row in your terms) is linear on the number of matching entries (if its hashed appropriately)

Comment: @Chad: for the delete operation they are (it should delete `T1` only when `T2` equals a specific value). for the rest, `T1` is the key and `T2` is the value.

Comment: Is a pair of T1 and T2 unique? Or can you have two items with the same T1 _and_ T2?

Comment: There is no data structure outside of an actual database that's going to give you all of your required performance characteristics at once. It is a very rare combination of functionality, needing to effectively use the value as a key, but only for deletion operations. How much do you really _need_ less than linear performance on deletion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you consider using a `std::set` ?

Using your elements as a single composite key:

- Insertion and Deletion are covered as usual.
- Search is covered by a combination of `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` (both O(log N)) which works as you can define a minimum and maximum elements for your pair.

Comment: How can I define a minimum and maximum for my pair?

Comment: @Dani: a pair is lexically ordered, therefore if you have a `pair<T,U>` the pair composed of the minimum of `T` and the minimum of `U` would be the minimum pair, and likewise for the maximum. If you are using numbers, you can include `<limits>` and then use: `std::numeric_limits<T>::min()` to get the minimum for your type.